# How to set CSS RGB colors using decimal values?

Tags: html, css, colors

I'm in new to HTML/CSS. I can see that there are various ways of setting color code in a CSS style description i.e. by name e.g. `yellow` or by hex code `#ffff00`. I see there are also decimal equivalents of each color e.g. yellow has decimal equivalent as `255,255,0` but applying the below style on my body element has no effect at all:

My CSS:

```
body {
background-color: 255,255,0;
color: black !important;
}
```

Can someone help me on this?

Comment: use **rgb(255,255,0)**  or **rgba(255,255,255,0.9)**

Comment: @ZaidBinKhalid you mean rgb(255,255,255) or rgba(255,255,255,.9) ?

Comment: @ZaidBinKhalid Cool. This works :) Thanks for your quick response. I used rgb(255,255,0) You might want to add this as an answer.

Comment: @RBT You very welcome.

Comment: *I tried googling the same but no luck*. I don't know about your googling skills, but if I type **CSS RGB**, I get back 20,200,000 results with all links on the first page pointing to exactly what you're after, that is the CSS `rgb()` function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like this

```
body {
    background-color: rgb(255,255,0);
}
```

To add opacity, use `rgba`. Where `1` is 100% opacity.

```
body {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,0, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**rgba(255,255,0,1)**
To add opacity, use rgba. Where 1 is 100% opacity.

```css
.body {
background-color: rgb(255,255,0);
color: black !important;
padding:25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="body"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to add this rule  to your css **rgb(0,0,0)** or **rgba(0,0,0,0.5)** to opacity.

```
body {
    background-color: rgb(255,255,0);
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.body {
background-color: rgb(255,255,0);
color: black !important;
padding:25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="body"></div>
```